# Why is the infinite dimensional unit ball perfectoid?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory

Reading Scholze and Weinstein: "Berkeley lectures on p-adic geometry" in the proof of lemma 19.3.5 they use that the infinite-dimensional ball $B^\infty_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ is affinoid perfectoid. I don't understand why this holds true. In contrast, the usual one-dimensional unit ball $B_{\mathbb{C}_p}=Spa(\mathbb{C}_p<T>,O_{\mathbb{C}_p}<T>)$ is not perfectoid. Can someone explain?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I have something to say on the topic, but not if this is old news to you.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. I should have replied to myself.